# vagrant virtualbox booting error

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I'm trying to launch vagrant 1.8.5 with a virtual box 1.5.x (i tried 1.5.4, 1.5.18 and 1.5.0).
When i launch vagrant with the commande : `vagrant up`, i had the error in the commande lines :

```
        Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
        ==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
        ==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
        ==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
        default: Adapter 1: nat
        ==> default: Forwarding ports...
        default: 80 (guest) => 8080 (host) (adapter 1)
        default: 3306 (guest) => 1234 (host) (adapter 1)
        default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
        ==> default: Booting VM...
        There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
        for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

        Command: ["startvm", "4d01469a-5cd7-4552-8185-c10098bf7efa", "--type", "headless
        "]

        Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: The virtual machine 'package_Php56_CentOs7_defaul
        t_1491408918425_94535' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code
        1 (0x1).  More details may be available in 'd:\Profiles\aelkari\VirtualBox VMs\
        package_Php56_CentOs7_default_1491408918425_94535\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'
        VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component MachineWrap,
        interface IMachine
```

the logs of virtualBox shows (VBoxHardening.log) :

```
        1d6c.10c8: supHardNtVpFreeOrReplacePrivateExecMemory: Replacing exec mem at 000000004c000000 (LB 0x1000, 000000004c000000 LB 0x1000)
        1d6c.10c8: supHardNtVpFreeOrReplacePrivateExecMemory: Free attempt #1 succeeded: 0x0 [000000004c000000/000000004c000000 LB 0/0x1000]
        1d6c.10c8: supHardNtVpFreeOrReplacePrivateExecMemory: QVM after free 0: [0000000000000000]/000000004c000000 LB 0x2bc50000 s=0x10000 ap=0x0 rp=0x00000000000001
        1d6c.10c8: Error (rc=-5673):
        1d6c.10c8: NtAllocateVirtualMemory (000000004c000000 LB 0x1000) failed with rcNt=0xc0000018 allocating replacement memory for working around buggy protection software. See VBoxStartup.log for more details
        1d6c.10c8: Error (rc=-5645):
        1d6c.10c8: Too many virtual memory regions.

        1d6c.10c8: Error (rc=-5673):
        1d6c.10c8: supHardenedWinVerifyProcess failed with Unknown Status -5673 (0xffffe9d7): NtAllocateVirtualMemory (000000004c000000 LB 0x1000) failed with rcNt=0xc0000018 allocating replacement memory for working around buggy protection software. See VBoxStartup.log for more details 
        [rc=-5645] Too many virtual memory regions.
        1d6c.10c8: Error -5673 in supR3HardNtChildPurify! (enmWhat=5)
        1d6c.10c8: supHardenedWinVerifyProcess failed with Unknown Status -5673 (0xffffe9d7): NtAllocateVirtualMemory (000000004c000000 LB 0x1000) failed with rcNt=0xc0000018 allocating replacement memory for working around buggy protection software. See VBoxStartup.log for more details 
        [rc=-5645] Too many virtual memory regions.
```

I'm working on windows7 64bits, my virtualisation is enabled (VT-D and Intel virtualisation technologie).

Someone know what is means 'Too many virtual memory regions' ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resolved my probleme :

set GUI=1
vagrant up

Have a good day

Comment: Did you add "set GUI=1" to the commandline before running vagrant up? Do you have a link to a source that suggested this change?